# Syntax error on using map, lambda and tuple in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have cloned a Github project which was developed in Python 2 and run it in Python 3.6, the following line gives "syntax error".

```
working_docs = [map(lambda (sid, sent): (sid, [sent]), d) for d in tokenized_docs]
```

The value for `tokenized_docs` is a list of list of tuples, see the screenshot below for value inspection. Please help.

[image]

Comment: error aside, this is a bad strategy, even if you don't get errors you should not just blindly run python 2 code on python 3 and *hope* it works

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I'm very new to Python and trying to evaluate existing projects. This line is a bit too complicated for me to grasp. I did spend time on it and couldn't make it work.
Can you please convert it into python 3? thanks.